# How can i clear the cache of image of my members

Tags: php, html

I code a site where people can create accounts and put a profile picture
The problem is that when people change their photo it keeps the same name and photo ducoup we always see his old photo
Is it possible to clear the cache of members' photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the cache-control and the expires META Tag.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">
```

Another common practices is to append constantly-changing strings to the end of the requested files. For instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?v=12392823"></script>
```

There is also server side caching whether it be with Memcached, or redist, or even just php's caching. It's hard to say for certain what all caching you're using.

Comment: Tim's suggestion of the `?stringstringstring` appended to filenames always works for me... +1